# How Nexus Proxy repository works?

Tags: nexus

How Proxy repository works in Nexus? I have configured a proxy repo and added it to group repo, which URL needs to be given to user to find artifacts?

Answer (score 1):

If you have added your proxy repository to your group repository then you can give group repository url to users.

Proxy repository works as a proxy for a hosted repository. When configuring proxy repository you should give URL of hosted repository in Remote Storage location.
for your refrence you have configure like this, give the URL of hosted repository in Remote Storage location

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the group repository URL to your users. Specifically it will depend on the repository format and the client side tool.

E.g. for Maven repositories you can use Maven, Gradle, Ant/Ivy and others and all of that is [documented nicely in the Nexus book](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/config.html) and there are also [working example projects available](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples).

Other formats like NPM, NuGet, RubyGems .. are also documented [there](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/index.html).